# How to use with `java` command with `kotlin-compiler.jar` to compile Kotlin source codes?

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

**I am now limited to use `java` command to compile a Kotlin source file.**

So after some attempts, I found a `kotlin-compiler.jar` file in the `lib/` folder in `kotlinc/`.

Then I tried to write a `Hello.kt` file **in `kotlinc/lib/`**:

```
public fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("hello")
}
```

And then, I executed the command `java -jar kotlin-compiler.jar Hello.kt` which worked and generated a class file `HelloKt.class`.

As a result I executed the command `java -cp ".:kotlin-runtime.jar" HelloKt`, and it also worked:

```
[xxxxxxx@uss lib]$ java -cp ".:kotlin-runtime.jar" HelloKt
hello
```

---

**But, for a more complicated source file:**

AimToTen.kt:

```
class AimToTen() {
    fun need(marks: Array<Int>): Int {
        // multiply 10 first
        for (idx: Int in marks.indices) marks[idx] *= 10

        val result: Int = 190 * marks.size - 2 * marks.sum();
        return when {
            result < 0 -> 0
            result % 10 != 0 -> result / 10 + 1
            else -> result / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to execute `java -jar kotlin-compiler.jar AimToTen.kt`, but some functions missed(?):

```
[xxxxxxx@uss intro1]$ java -jar kotlin-compiler.jar AimToTen.kt
AimToTen.kt:4:32: error: unresolved reference: indices
        for (idx: Int in marks.indices) marks[idx] *= 10
                               ^
AimToTen.kt:10:56: error: unresolved reference: sum
        val result: Int = 190 * marks.size - 2 * marks.sum();
                                                       ^
```

---

So I tried again:

```
[xxxxxxx@uss intro1]$ java -jar kotlin-compiler.jar
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.0.3 (JRE 1.8.0_65-b17)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>> println(123)
error: unresolved reference: println
println(123)
^

>>> var test: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2)
>>> test
[I@7d64e326
>>>
```

Also, in other folder, the `Hello.kt` cannot be compiled even if I copied all the `.jar` files in the same folder.

---

**Ehh, I do appreciate if you can help me with this issue! I want to compile this file with `java` command, without any absolute paths.**

*P.S. Using `kotlinc AimToTen.kt` works.*

Comment: you are missing `kotlin-stdlib` somewhere. Try adding it to the compiler options

Comment: @voddan That's what I thought, but how to add it? The `stdlib` you mentioned seems to be `kotlin-runtime.jar`, which I've already tried: `java -cp kotlin-runtime.jar -jar kotlin-compiler.jar AimToTen.kt` and `java -cp ".:kotlin-runtime.jar" -jar kotlin-compiler.jar AimToTen.kt` resulted in failure. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html), the line to compile a Kotlin file is

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
```

BTW, if you are trying to learn/try out Kotlin in command line (which you should not!), you may consider http://try.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: Thanks, but `scala` and `clojure` are all able to be compiled by `java` command. So I think `Kotlin` should be as well. Additionally, the `kotlinc` is a bash file and what command it's using is actually `java xxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: @MewX Use the script. That's what it's for.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, but why the script needs the installed path? I was wondering what files are required in the compiling procedure.